# Why am I getting this Qiskit Error code: 'qr' not defined?

Tags: python-3.x, quantum-computing, qiskit

[Qiskit error code 'qr' not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLxcg.png)

It should be defined I expect. It may be the difference in the version of software on the video I watched vs my software. I tried 'import qiskit' and it still gave me the error code. I'm not sure but I'm just starting out and it's being real funky. Suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean to type `qr = QuantumRegister(2)`? Looks like a typo.

Comment: use from qiskit import * (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[mre]" and all their linked pages, along with [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421) and [Link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is because you have not created a quantum register. You can do this by using the following code.

```
# Define a quantum register named 'qr' with 1 qubit
qr = QuantumRegister(1)
```